# select datapoint on ggplot to generate table only shows on desktop/laptop not mobile

Tags: r, ggplot2, shinydashboard, ggplotly

Below are the code sample I found on https://mastering-shiny.org/action-graphics.html.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("plot", brush = "plot_brush"),
  tableOutput("data")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()
  }, res = 96)
  
  output$data <- renderTable({
    brushedPoints(mtcars, input$plot_brush)
  })
```

The code is working on shiny desktop; however, it wont generate the table on mobile device.
Please help!

Comment: This functionality is not supported on mobile. Nothing we can do. You need to find an alternative Javascript library to do so.

Comment: @lz100 can you please point me to the right direction. Which JS library are you referring to?

Comment: I know `plotly` also has the brush, but not sure how it works on mobile. Not aware of other libraries.